# If $-2\leq f(x)\leq 4$ for all real $x$, then which must exist? $\lim_{x\to-2}\frac1{f(x)}$, $\lim_{x\to-2}\frac{f(x)}x$, $\lim_{x\to-2}(|f(x)|-f(x))$

Tags: calculus, limits

This question was my exam question. I believe it may be wrong.

> The function $f(x)$ defined in the set of real numbers is given for all $x$ as follows:
> $$-2\leq f(x)\leq 4$$
> Which of the following statements is always true?
>
> 1. $\lim_{x\to -2}\dfrac 1{f(x)}$ exists.
> 2. $\lim_{x\to -2}\dfrac {f(x)}{x}$ exists.
> 3. $\lim_{x\to -2} (|f(x)|-f(x))$ exists.
>
> A) $1 \qquad$ B) $2 \qquad$ C) only $3 \qquad$ D) $1$ and $2\qquad$ E) $2$ and $3$

This is what I wrote on the exam paper:

Let

$$\begin{align}f(x)=\begin{cases}-1,\; \text{if}\,x>-2\\
\phantom{-}0,\;\text{if}\,x=-2\\
\phantom{-}3,\;\text{if}\,x<-2\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Then we have

$\lim_{x\to -2}\dfrac 1{f(x)}$ doesn't exist

Because,

$$\lim_{x\to -2^+}\frac 1{f(x)}\neq\lim_{x\to -2^-}\frac 1{f(x)}$$

---

$\lim_{x\to -2}\dfrac {f(x)}{x}$ doesn't exist.

Because

$$\lim_{x\to -2^+}\frac {f(x)}{x}=\phantom{-}\frac 12$$

$$\lim_{x\to -2^-}\frac {f(x)}{x}=-\frac 32 $$

---

$\lim_{x\to -2} (|f(x)|-f(x))$ doesn't exist.

Because,

$$\lim_{x\to -2^+} (|f(x)|-f(x))=1+1=2$$

$$\lim_{x\to -2^-} (|f(x)|-f(x))=3-3=0$$

---

And on the exam paper, I wrote the question asked is wrong.

Please, tell me what have I done?

Comment: Did they forget to specify that $f(x)$ is continuous?

Comment: It looks like they’re missing a hypothesis that $f$ is continuous or differentiable. Your counterexample looks good.

Comment: Your solution looks ok, I would guess the question forgot to mention $f$ is continuous, in which case only one of the statements is correct.

Comment: I think the exam wanted you to assume the function is continuous, thats why one of the answers is correct, otherwise if it did not, then its in your favour...

Comment: @5xum Thank you for comment, if $f(x)$ is continuous then I think the statement $2$ is always true,...Right?

Comment: @I'mastudent Actually, my comment was a little rushed, yes, statement 2 is always true, but it is not the only one.

Comment: I believe so, statement 2 will be always true then. Statement 1 fails when f(-2)=0

Comment: @5xum I can not find a counterexample for the statement $3$...

Comment: @I'mastudent That's because there isn't one.

Comment: @5xum Thank you very much!

Comment: @Teddy38 Yes, it is not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is fine but, as mentioned in the comments, the function was probably intended to be continuous. In any case, it is a flaw in the question and you have a good point in case you are not awarded the full score.

If $f$ is continuous:

$(1)$ is not true in general (requires $f(-2) \ne 0$).

$(2)$ is always true, with the limit being $-\frac 12 f(-2)$.

$(3)$ is always true but the value of the limit depends on the sign of $f(-2)$.

Comment: A bit more explicitly, the limit in (3) is $\lvert f(-2)\rvert - f(-2)$, because if $f$ is continuous, then so is $x\mapsto\lvert f(x)\rvert$ .

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch yes, that's it :)

Comment: Thank you. Then I won't get full points on the question...  Because I did not write anything about the $f$ is continuous..

Comment: @I'mastudent The function being continuous is an assumption that needs to be *given* in the exercise, not in the answer. If it was not given, then the exercise in the form you posted here is ill-posed and you may rightfully complain about that.

Comment: @I'mastudent If the continuity was not mentioned in the question, your answer is perfect: It shows that, in general, none of the statements is true.

Comment: Yes, continuity is never mentioned in the question.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Thank you very much.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I need more explanation for the statement $3$...If $f$ is continuous can we write $f(-2)=\lim_{x\to -2} f(-2)$ ?..

Comment: @I'mastudent that is the precise definition of $f$ being continuous. (but I guess you meant $f(-2)=\lim_{x \to -2} f(x)$)

Comment: Oh Thank you very much.!

Comment: So, the limit is equal to $0$ or $-2f(-2)$ Am I right?

Comment: Yes, like @MaximilianJanisch mentioned, $\lim_{x\to -2}(|f(x)|-f(x)) = |f(-2)|-f(-2)$, and this value behaves as you mention.